# Disable studio/publisher credits during startup

Tags: civilization-5

The latest Civ5 patch has added three short but annoying movies displaying the logo of the publishers. Is there a way to disable these so the game loads faster?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason you can't instantly skip through the intro movie right away -- the game is actually already loading while it shows you those publishers' logos. Skipping them would just mean you're looking at a blank screen a little longer.

Comment: I've had the intro movie disabled for a long while, and the game seems to take longer to get to the main menu now. I would honestly prefer a blank screen like before to seeing branding ads in a game I purchased. :P

Answer (score 2):

To disable those logos at startup, remove (or rename) all the `*opening_movie*.mov` files in your civilization folder. In my case those where:

```
civ5_opening_movie_de_de.mov
civ5_opening_movie_fr_fr.mov
civ5_opening_movie_en_us.mov
assets/dlc/expansion/civ5xp_opening_movie_en_us.mov
assets/dlc/expansion2/civ5xp2_opening_movie_en_us.mov
```